# Jquery Fittext not work with bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, fittextjs

JSFiddle

```
Link jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/jimmyphong/867wvc9u/2/
```

Im using jquery Fittext with bootstrap carousel , for first and active item work fine , so with another item or (hidden maybe) it not work !

any help !

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its an old question but here is a quick solution if anyone else come seek for an answer.

bootstrap have 2 triggers in the carousel plugin `slide` and `slid` ([Read Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)). But you can not use `slide` as it triggers just before it starts sliding and that stage the next slide is in `display:none` and fitText plugin will add the `minFontSize` to it. And you can use `slid`. It will trigger just after sliding is completed. So in this case to avoid flickering on this we need to find a place where it has to be just after `display:none` is gone. so the ideal place is animated state. So in order to do that you need to observe the element with class change and trigger a element resize.

Please find below the solution,

Initiate fitText, [Documentation](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js)

```
$(".fittext").fitText(0.2, { minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '100px' });
```

Write an observer extension to jquery `addClass`

```
// Extends functionality of ".addClass()"
(function(){
    var originalAddClassMethod = jQuery.fn.addClass;
    $.fn.addClass = function(){
        var result = originalAddClassMethod.apply( this, arguments );
        $(this).trigger('addClassChanged');
        return result;
    }
})();
```

And run the element resize event on class change.

```
$('.carousel-item').on('addClassChanged', function(){
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/867wvc9u/12/

---

***Note:-** Since `resize` event keeps listen to the DOM, we can tweak the fitText plugin a bit to overcome unexpected call stack overkill issues.*

Update the window event line in the fitText plugin.

```
...
$(window).on('resize.fittext click.fittext orientationchange.fittext', resizer);
...
```

and do a `click` instead, in the `addClassChanged` event,

```
$('.carousel-item').on('addClassChanged', function(){
    $(window).click();
});
```